# Is it better to bootstrap a step-down converter from the input or the output?

Tags: bootstrap

The title may be not put so well. What I want to know is if it is better to draw energy for bootstrapping **from the input** like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fskAYU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or is it better **drawing energy from the output** like this?:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8kdrx.png)</sup>

This question came to my mind when I saw on [page 8 in this datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/412/ACT4088_Data_Sheet-1714846.pdf) the option to use Vin or Vout for bootstrapping:

[image]

I think it is best to use the input for bootstrapping, since you don't want to draw more current from your output, since you want it to be as steady as possible in a switch mode supply/IC.

In my case, Vin=5V, and Vout=3.3V.

Comment: The first has the merit that the circuit can start up because C1 is charged from Vin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick whichever has the most convenient voltage. Usually the supply providing power to the output is far too high voltage and the logic supply is closer.

But in your second drawing you imply you want to grab the output of the stepdown converter. That doesn't make sense since it can never start up. You would need to grab the output of the supply you are stepping down.

As for the third drawing, I don't understand how it is possible to use Vout if Vout is truly the output of the ACT4088.

**CLARIFICATION:**

You have three "possible" options: Vcc, Vin, and Vout. Your third diagram us using Vout. But if Vout is zero before starting up, and needs to not be zero to run then it can never start up. Catch-22. You can't use Vout. You can, however, use Vin but it is often too high.

[image]
From Linear Technology [LTC444 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4444.pdf)

Comment: Hm i cant understand to what voltages/supplies are you referring to. The third image i posted refers to (i think) connecting the Diode to either the input of the step down converter (which i call Vin) OR the output of the step down converter (which i call Vout). And those are the two options i was asking about. are there more suitable voltages to connect the bootstrap diode to? 

Also, When you say "Usually the supply providing power to the output" aren't you referring to the Vout?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios See edit.